# Confused in basic hex subtraction

Tags: arithmetic

I am having trouble thinking in hex terms when making hex subtraction.
Example: I am trying to do: `0x503c - 0x40`
I am stuck in the part subtracting the 4 from 3. I understand that since in the next position we have 0 we must "borrow" from the 5 i.e. removing a `16^3` (leaving 4 as the first digit) but I am stuck on how to distribute this `16^3` to the next 2 figures so as to do the subtraction.
In decimal e.g. the 100 borrowed would be a 90 and a 10 (ever the decimal and digit column) but I am confused with the hex arithmetic.
Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Recall, in hex, you are borrowing groups of $16_{10}$.

So, we have:

$$0x503C - 0x40$$

- We can subtract $0$ from $C$ = $C$
- We need to borrow, so we borrow a $16$ from $5$, making that position a $4$. This makes the second position a $16$, but we need to borrow $1$ from it, leaving $F$.
- We needed and borrowed a 16 for the third position, so now have $16 + 3  - 4 = 15 = F$.

Writing the result yields:

$$0x503C - 0x40 = 0x 4FFC$$

Comment: Good work! Keeps you sharp ;-) (+)

Comment: `This makes the second position a 16`. How can this hold? The digits are only 0-F so how can the second position be 16?

Comment: How does a digit move to the next state? You go from 15 to 16. When you go back, you bring all 16 with you. Clear? You are borrowing a 16 from the left digit. Remember, each bit in hex represent $16$.

Comment: Write out $16^3 | 16^2 | 16^1 | 16^0$. What happens if you take the $16^1$ bit and move it right?

Answer (score 0):

To subtract `0x0040` from `0x503C`:

$C-0=C$

$3-4=F$, borrow one

$0-(0+\color{red}1)=F$, borrow one

$5-(0+\color{red}1)=4$.

Done: `0x4FFC`. The method is really the same as with decimal notation.

Comment: It is the borrowing part that I don't understand in the first place